# Rails in production + Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I enter in console:

```
git push heroku master
```

I get:

```
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Would have removed sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Would have removed sass (3.2.5)
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (13.99s)
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 12.0MB
-----> Launching... done, v7
       http://chernobylmusic.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

Running:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

The result is:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.5186
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
```

and the migrations are applied.

When I visit my page on Heroku, I see `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

Comment: Track the heroku logs and paste it.. thn only we can help you out

Comment: http://old.pastie.org/6370337

Answer (score 6):

Run `heroku logs` and look at the errors

Answer (score 0):

The error log says

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "events" does not exist
```

Which means you don't have a DB created and even you don't have you migrations run. Check if you have pg gem in your Gemfile.  If not  Add `gem 'pg'` in the production block of your Gemfile as Heroku runs on postgres.

thn do a

```
git push heroku master
```

thn

```
heroku run rake db:create
```

thn

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

It should work.

Comment: Doesn't heroku error out during deploy if `pg` is not in the Gemfile?

Comment: @technobot check the logs now it says undefined method 'img' on `@events.reverse.last.img` ... plz check the img is a valid attribute.

Comment: i adding in migrations files Event.create img:"events/01.png" + Release.create img: "releases/01.png". it work! thanks you mates!